# How to realise Android Components Material Design in https://material.io ? I can't find the demo

Tags: android, material-design

I'm focusing on Material design realization on Android and I find there are many awesome transactions and animations in https://material.io. Such as: [A floating action button transforming into a toolbar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)

I know the transactions and animations is realised based on `FabActionButton`(or the newly v7 widget, ButtonNavigationView ) but I can'd find the official demos!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try out Chris Banes's [Cheesesquare Sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

It shows some of the important features in the Design library:

- Collapsing Toolbar
- FloatingActionButton
- View anchoring
- NavigationView
- Snackbar

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Do you mean Google didn't offer the official implementations of the 'transactions and animations' ?